# VSCode debugger for Rust does not expand variable in filter section

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to configure my VSCode for debugging directly from source code.

I have created the following configuration in `launch.json`:

```json
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug executable for current file (with no parameters)",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    // "--package==",
                    "--manifest-path=${fileDirname}/../Cargo.toml"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        },
```

But this is not working. It fails with "Cargo has produced no matching compilation artifacts." (Notice than I have more than one bin in `Cargo.toml`)

But if I change the line from

```json
"name": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
```

to

```json
"name": "main",
```

it works

So, I suspect that VSCode is not expanding the variable `${fileBasenameNoExtension}` in filter section.

I have 2 questions:

- How can I check if is a problem of variable expansion or other?
- And, if is a problem of variable expansion, how to workaround it?

NOTE: I think is not relevant, but this my `Cargo.toml` file

```ini
[package]
name = "mytest"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "src/main.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "main2"
path = "src/main2.rs"


[dependencies]
```

Comment: totally off but I think debugger is time lost :p I would advice you to do tracing log macro.